# Why am I not being notified of downvotes on philosophy.meta.stackexchange

Tags: discussion, voting

Why am I not being notified of downvotes on philosophy.meta.stackexchange? Can I lose question privileges due to these downvotes?

[Are too many questions being closed because of how they are phrased?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3448/are-too-many-questions-being-closed-because-of-how-they-are-phrased)

[What does the "not useful" downvote mean on philosophy.stackexchange?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3460/what-does-the-not-useful-downvote-mean-on-philosophy-stackexchange)

[Can I stop someone answering my questions?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3453/can-i-stop-someone-answering-my-questions)

[Is philosophy a good fit for stackexchange?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3450/is-philosophy-a-good-fit-for-stackexchange)

Incidentally, I don't quite understand all these votes (as indicated by the 2nd question above). Maybe my tone is being misunderstood?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not notified of any votes here because they don't change your reputation. Also because of this, you cannot lose privileges here.